# How to use async await in python falcon?

Tags: python, async-await, falconframework

I am looking for example of using async await features of python 3. I am using falcon framework for building rest api. Can't figure out how to use async await with it.

Please help me, by providing some examples, maybe with other frameworks.

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the time the request take to be fulfiled, you could use [celery](docs.celeryproject.org/), which is a task queue, or maybe use webhooks?

Comment: If you are willing to use another framework, have a look at [sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic). It seems to be made for that exact purpose. I have not tried it myself yet, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: as of [Falcon 3.0](https://pypi.org/project/falcon/3.0.0), the framework supports `async` / `await` via the ASGI protocol.

In order to write async Falcon code, you need to use [the ASGI flavour of `App`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/app.html#asgi-app), for instance:

```python
import http

import falcon
import falcon.asgi


class MessageResource:
    def __init__(self):
        self._message = 'Hello, World!'

    async def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.media = {'message': self._message}

    async def on_put(self, req, resp):
        media = await req.get_media()
        message = media.get('message')
        if not message:
            raise falcon.HTTPBadRequest

        self._message = message
        resp.status = http.HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT


app = falcon.asgi.App()
app.add_route('/message', MessageResource())
```

Assuming the above snippet is saved as `test.py`, the ASGI application can be run as

```
uvicorn test:app
```

Setting and retrieving the message with [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/):

```
$ http PUT http://localhost:8000/message message=StackOverflow
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
server: uvicorn
```

```
$ http http://localhost:8000/message 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 28
content-type: application/json
server: uvicorn

{
    "message": "StackOverflow"
}
```

**Note** that when using the ASGI flavour of Falcon, all responders, hooks, middleware methods, error handlers etc must be awaitable coroutine functions, as the framework does not perform any implicit wrapping or scheduling in an executor.

See also [Falcon's ASGI tutorial](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/tutorial-asgi.html).